# layout alignment

Tags: html, css, layout, header, alignment

My blogs layout [here](http://www.gilliansbeauty.blogspot.co.uk), needs to move over to the left a bit but when I try to move the header image, it goes so far to the left then part of it disappears.

I'd appreciate anyone being able to tell me how to fix this.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
To learn how to ask questions that work on this site please read [ask], especially  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In this case you should explain (in code) what you've tried.

Comment: That template is pathetically designed. I have tried and achieved to center the content but that border is giving headache. This is what will happen when you go for these kind of templates which are coded will absolute sizes and positions. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/2356033831-widget_css_2_bundle.css

Edit that css file and add a width rule to the content class

from

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

to

```
.content{
    position: relative;
    width: 1280px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```